# Android - unlocking keypad, can't open urls in browser later

Tags: android

I have an alarm app, when the alarm is raised it unlocks the screen if locked, then proceeds to another activity in my app. In that activity there's a link that when clicked takes the user to an url.

This is how the link opens:

```
linkView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        goToBrowser(context, url);
    }
});
```

and this is the method used:

```
public static void goToBrowser(Context context, String url){
    try {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Browser badness", e);
    }
}
```

Now this works fine when the alarm is raised with an unlocked keypad. The url is valid. When the alarm is raised from a locked keypad though, it successfully unlocks the screen and proceeds to the next activity, but then tapping the link just opens the browser without going to the url. I'm testing on a secure keyguard with a pin. I'm curios why there's a difference in the behaviour, looks like the secure keyguard removes some permissions, I couldn't find much resources that would explain this. Any good read explaining the specifics of the secure keyguards in android is appreciated, I couldn't find any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, answering my own question in case someone finds it useful. Seems like a secured keypad in android is a pretty big and messy deal, and though an app can unlock the keypad, that unlock is useful only in the context of the app, at least that's what I came up with after a few more hours of experimenting. I'd gladly accept any other answer that gives an example of how this can be done, for now I'll change my code and application flow to consider the secured keypad and not try to bypass it.